# Using Input Box to conduct a VLookUp

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I keep getting a type mismatch when I run my code. I have defined the range QBs in excel already and cannot figure out the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub cmdQB_Click()
    'define variables
    Dim strName As String, rank As String, rngQBs As Range
    Dim shtProjections As Worksheet
    Set shtProjections = Application.Workbooks("finalProjectProjections.xlsm").Worksheets("Projections")
    Set rngQBs = shtProjections.Range("QBs")

    strName = InputBox("Enter QB name", "QBs")
    If Len(strName) > 0 Then
        rank = Application.VLookup(strName, shtProjections.Range("QBs"), 1, False)
        MsgBox " & strName & ", "is ranked" & rank
    Else
        MsgBox "The player is not ranked."
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: Perhaps the string is not found. Is QBs a named range?

Comment: `rank = Application.VLookup(strName, shtProjections.Range("QBs"), 1, False)` - that will throw an error if the vlookup doesn't find `strName`  - you need to test with `IsError`.

Comment: And declare it as a `variant`.

Comment: `MsgBox " & strName & ", "is ranked" & rank` should be `MsgBox strName & ", is ranked" & rank`

Comment: @SJR QBs is a named range, the type mismtach error pops up before the Vlookup code runs,  but works up until the line 'If Len(strName) > 0 Then'

Comment: @SJR the Line that errors is 'code' rank = Application.VLookup(strName, shtProjections.Range("QBs"), 1, False) 'code' the value of strName is what the user puts in the input box, such as "Lamar Jackson" which is on the list in the QBs range

Comment: Did you take the advice and change the declaration of the variable to Variant: `rank As Variant`?

Comment: Yes I changed the code to "rank As Variant"

Comment: Vlookup on text strings that are user controlled is very problematic, as the spelling and spacing must be exact for it to find a match.  Most likely you are not spelling the names exactly the same or the data has extra spaces or other unprintable characters which is causing the vlookup not to find a match.  When it does not find a match the vlookup will return an error and you cannot put an error in a string variable.

Comment: With it as variant I bet the error has now moved to the next line as you cannot concatenate an error with a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub cmdQB_Click()
    'define variables
    Dim strName As String, rank As Variant, rngQBs As Range
    Dim shtProjections As Worksheet
    Set shtProjections = Application.Workbooks("finalProjectProjections.xlsm").Worksheets("Projections")
    Set rngQBs = shtProjections.Range("QBs")

    strName = InputBox("Enter QB name", "QBs")
    If Len(strName) > 0 Then
        rank = Application.VLookup(strName, shtProjections.Range("QBs"), 1, False)
        If Not IsError(rank) Then
            MsgBox strName & ", is ranked" & rank
        Else
            MsgBox strName & " is not found in list"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "You did not enter a name"
    End If

End Sub
```